# Job failure on OData - OData source was unable to process the data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata, etl

I have a SSIS package which pulls data from OData source and stores it in database at local server. This package runs perfectly at a scheduled time daily but sometimes the package execution fails and i get the job failure notification. The error comes as

> 'OData source was unable to process the data'.

However i can run the job manually later and the job runs all good and i am getting the data. But i am looking for the solution for this, so that the automatic package execution is never a failure.

*P.S. There is no change in the table or data structure.*

Please, any insight will be helpfull.

Comment: can you provide the ODATA connection manager and the ODATA Source properties (screenshots)?

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused due to a Timeout expiration, or due to the message maximum size.

Try changing the corresponding values in the ODATA connection manager

[image]

**References**

- [HELP: Error during data read using OData source - SSIS 2012 or superior](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64557bcd-a46b-4dce-93a3-0dd1b22b67b1/help-error-during-data-read-using-odata-source-ssis-2012-or-superior?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Thanks Hadi, I dont think it may be the timeout issue because the job run for 2 mins only and data loaded for 2 tables, after that while loading the 3rd table the error is thrown.

Comment: Try changing the retry count and max message size. Else what is the account running the job? Is it the same that you are running manually?